# segmentation fault when gdb_init called

Tags: python, gdb

I have written a wrapper program for `gdb` and to start with it will call `gdb_init` where it checks for python version which gets failed resulting segmentation fault.

My machine is 64bit linux box where we have requirement of 32 bit `gdb`, and its related packages. Considering that I have already put `python` and `python-devel` 32 bit packages as well. Along with that all the code is also compiled with `-m32`.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])

   int main_pid = atoi(argv[3]);
   ddb_ops.pid=main_pid;
   ddb_ops.get_regs = getRegister;
   ddb_ops.attach = attachThread;
   ios::sync_with_stdio();
   init_libgdb(argv[1], argv[2]);
   flush_process_state();
```

Here is the stackback which I am getting..

```
Starting program: test proc1 1.rxt
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x083203e6 in lbasename ()
(gdb) bt
     #0  0x083203e6 in lbasename ()
     #1  0x08202705 in ldirname ()
     #2  0x080df54a in _initialize_python ()
     #3  0x081fefef in gdb_init ()
     #4  0x080909cf in init_libgdb (symfile=0xffffcef8 "proc1", outfile=0xffffcefe "1.txt")      at ../gdbinterface.c:785
     #5  0x08090d0b in main (argc=5, argv=0xffffcc74) at ../test.cpp:79
```

Any help will be really appreciated..

Comment: Please show us your `test.cpp`

Comment: Added the snippet of test.cpp

Answer (score 0):

You have to set python_libdir at startup.

If you want to have your own driver you will just have to dig into the details.  This isn't a supported thing to do with the gdb internals.

Comment: Tom, Thanks for your reply, Can you let me know how to set  python_libdir for gdb?

Comment: I think you should look at the gdb source and see what it is doing.  You are in DIY territory.